# What is the difference between kFIREventSearch and kFIREventViewSearchResults?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

There are 2 built in Firebase analytics event type related to search which is kFIREventSearch and kFIREventViewSearchResults.

When a user searches for something (for example "turtles" on Google), doesn't it mean that the user also immediately views the search results? When should I use which? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

kFIREventSearch revolves around the search terms themselves and kFIREventViewSearchResults is related to the results of the search.  Eventually, this will tie into remarketing, if you run remarketing campaigns on the items in the search results.